# What does coat of no cut and no time mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, charles-dickens

> This reference to the coat of no cut and no time, the unfortunate gentleman gasped forth, in a scarcely audible voice, and with his clenched pocket-handkerchief raised in the air.

What does "coat of no cut and no time" mean in the preceding passage from Dickens' Little Dorrit Chapter 31?

Comment: The language in *Little Dorrit*, written more than 150 years ago, is almost meaningless to this native speaker. I have found other novels by Dickens easier to follow.

Comment: @Lambie: No. The reference is to ***one*** thing. A thing that has ***two*** attributes - or more precisely, ***lacks*** two attributes (neither a known "cut", nor a style associated with any particular period). But in truth those two things overlap anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Yes, the coat is OF no cut **and** OF no time, but my parse is right. I didn't bother to explain the whole thing. But still, it is not one thing but two.

Comment: @Lambie Your original slashes ("_This reference to //the coat of no cut//and//no time_. ") seem to indicate that you parse it as the combination of "This reference to the coat of no cut." plus "This reference to no time." -- This is opposed to "This reference to the coat of no cut." plus "This reference to the coat of no time.", which I assume would be slashed as "_This reference to the coat of //no cut//and//no time._" (That is, "no time" is parallel to "no cut", both belonging to a single coat, rather than being a separate thing parallel to the full phrase "the coat of no cut".)

Comment: @R.M. You can turn it any way you like. The fact remains I said it was two things, Obviously, the "**of** no time" is implied, sure., That does not make my parse inaccurate.

Answer (score 10):

The highlighted text refers back to a line in [the very first paragraph](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/963/963-h/963-h.htm) of the containing chapter...

> *His coat is a colour, and cut, that never was the mode anywhere, at any period.*

I assume the reference to "colour" is self-explanatory. The "cut" of an item of clothing refers to how the different pieces of cloth making up a garment are shaped and stitched together so as to fit the body well (or hang down elegantly, as appropriate). And *never was the mode* is just a slightly "literary" alternative to ***was never fashionable / in fashion.***

So the text is saying the coat was very "unusual" - probably not in a *good* way, but the OP here can decide for himself whether it's an unusually good or unusually bad looking coat.

Comment: I'll just add this as a comment, because it's not really a necessary part of the above Answer, but I was genuinely surprised to find how often the word ***coat*** occurs in Little Dorrit. When searching for the "antecedent" referent (which logically *had* to exist earlier in the text) I just started searching the full text (as per link in the Answer) ***forwards** from the beginning*. And I had to wade through *dozens* of instances before I got to the one I was looking for. (I should've started by finding ***coat of no cut***, and searched ***backwards*** for the nearest preceding instance! :)

Comment: Putting on my "literary critic" hat, I assume it's no accident Dickens likes referring to coats. As a general principle, the kind of coat you wear is often seen as a reliable indicator of your social status (poor people are "ragamuffins" dressed in rags and tatters while the stereotypical cartoon millionaire wears a fur coat and smokes a fat cigar). Several of Dickens' stories turn on the idea of a central character who ***appears*** to be "low-born" (being poor and thus poorly-dressed), but is actually from a high-status background (and thus "lives happily ever after" at the end of the book).